# How to await on Future in from the different thread?

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio, twisted

I have a code that returns `Twisted` `Deferred` and I need to await on that deferred so I can use the usual `async-await` pattern further. So I am converting the `Deferred` returned from `Twisted` to A `Future`, like this:

```
future  = twisted_deferred.asFuture(asyncio.get_event_loop())
result = await future
```

After that, the code hangs on `await` expression, even though I can debug that the `set_result` is called on this particular future. After additional debugging, I discovered I am calling `await` on the Future on Thread1.
And in the `Deferred` result callback(where `set_result` is called) I am ending up in the MainThread, so I assume this is the problem here. The current event loop is the same as in the Future created, though.

Could someone explain why `await` is never returned? And how to properly implement the workflow so it actually awaits and returns the result when its ready?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all Twisted APIs must be used in the thread in which the reactor is running.  If an API is safe for use in a different thread it will be clearly marked as such.

The behavior of Twisted APIs when called from a non-reactor thread is unspecified.

If you you have code running in a different thread and you want to use some piece of Twisted functionality from it, you can use [reactor.callFromThread](https://docs.twisted.org/en/stable/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorFromThreads.html#callFromThread) or [blockingCallFromThread](https://docs.twisted.org/en/stable/api/twisted.internet.threads.html#blockingCallFromThread).